# Opencv minMaxLoc parameters

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram

I don't understand what parameter of minMaxLoc expresses or means the color.
parameters: 
maxVal – pointer to the returned maximum value; NULL is used if not required.
maxLoc – pointer to the returned maximum location (in 2D case); NULL is used if not required.

Is it maxVal or maxLoc??

Comment: it's maxLoc. you get maxVal, if you look at that place in the result Mat

Answer (score 1):

This sentence seems suspicious:

> I don't understand what parameter of minMaxLoc expresses or means the color

reading the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20minMaxLoc%28InputArray%20src,%20double%2a%20minVal,%20double%2a%20maxVal,%20Point%2a%20minLoc,%20Point%2a%20maxLoc,%20InputArray%20mask%29), I see the phrase

> The functions do not work with multi-channel arrays

This means single channel (eg. greyscale) only. The docs do also suggest ways in which a colour image may be altered to a single channel.

Anyway, as regards the parameters: `maxVal` is the actual *value* of the image at the maximum point. `maxLoc` is the location of that point. Sounds like you want `maxVal`. If you were expecting some sort of RGB value, then you evidently missed the important bit of the docs that I repeated above.